# Writing test case for keystore.load(InputStream,password)

Tags: java, junit, mockito, keystore, powermockito

I have been trying to write a test case for a `SSLContextCongif.java` class. There's a code section for which I have been having a hard time writing test case for:

```
KeyStore ks = KeyStore.getInstance("JKS");

ks.load(new FileInputStream(trustStore), password);

TrustManagerFactory trustManagerFactory = 
TrustManagerFactory.getInstance("PKIX");
trustManagerFactory.init(ks);
```

Test section i have written for this:

```
keystore=PowerMockito.mock(KeyStore.class);
trustManagerFactory =mock(TrustManagerFactory.class); 

String keys="mockedkeys";     

keystore = KeyStore.getInstance("JKS");
keystore.load(File(keys), password);

trustManagerFactory= TrustManagerFactory.getInstance("PKIX");
trustManagerFactory.init(keystore);
```

But here's the issue, the test case throws an exception at `ks.load()` *An exception occurred during setting up SSL context. {}*

Comment: I am not sure what you are trying to accomplish here. If you just want to mock the `KeyStore` and `TrustManagerFacotry` to do nothing you have to mock it, using `mockStatic` and having the `getInstance` return the mocks you want them to return. Your test however overrides the mocks you created with real files?

Comment: I tried using `mockStatic` also, but when i try to return mock with the `getInstance` it throws _Missing method invocation exception_.

Comment: Also the mocks are not overriding with the real file, that's seems to be problem here. It is actually loading the InputStream into engine.

Comment: You might want to update your question with the new code and the related stacktrace.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no way i could find to mock keystore.load() function. So I passed dummy keystore file with it's respective password. Worked like a charm.